# Subnetting IPv6 addresses/routes

Tags: routing, ipv6, subnet

I would like to subnet the default IPv6 route into 2 network routes. The original default route was:

```
default via fe80::218:74ff:fe27:9640 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024
```

I tried adding the following 2 routes, which together should be equivalent to the default route:

```
ip -6 route add ::/1 dev eth0 via fe80::218:74ff:fe27:9640  
ip -6 route add 80::/1 dev eth0 via fe80::218:74ff:fe27:9640
```

The first command went through, but the second one generated an error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Why is this happening? What's the correct way to specify 2 network routes covering everything?

Comment: Isn't `::/1` shorthand for 'everything'? Why do you think the 80::/1 is necessary?

Comment: @growse `::/0` would be everything, `::/1` is `::` through `7fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` - every address where the first bit (the `/1` mask) is a 0.

Answer (score 4):

`80::` is `0080::/1`, which isn't a valid route - try `8000::/1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The route should be 8000::/1. It's not a good idea though... All public IPv6 traffic uses 2000::/3, which will use ::/1. All ULA traffic (for example) will use the other route, but if you want that then you should create a default route (::/0) and a route for the ULA addresses (fc00::/7). Splitting on 8000::/1 does not make a lot of sense...